# How to make a Heroku app load server.js file

Tags: javascript, heroku, server, backend, host

I have a MERN stack deployed to heroku and inside my app I have a contact form that sends me an email. Naturally this uses post requests and a back end setup. I thought that heroku would start my back end server since the only dyno on my app is "npm start" which should launch the server. However, this server is only set up to run on my local host on whatever port I pick so I guess it makes sense that it doesn't work. I'm not very sure how all of this stuff works. I do know that everything works fine when I have the server loaded and running on my computer, but the second I turn that server off my heroku app can no longer access the back end. Is there something wrong with how I have this set up?? I've pretty much copied the example code so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if I'm actually expected to have this server running on a localhost:PORT for eternity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:  I think I see the error, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I send the post request with this line:

```
axios.post( "http://localhost:5000/sendEmail" || "http://ethanmeitz.com/sendEmail"   , data)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data))
        .then((response) => {
            if(response.statusText === "OK" && response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                return response.json()
            } else {
                throw new Error("Server can't be reached!")
            }
        })
        .then((json) => {
            console.log("It is JSON")
         })
        .catch(err => console.log('Could not send email: ' + err));
      }
```

But if heroku changes the port this won't work. Whats the URL I'm supposed to send the post request to given that heroku may change the ports and that environment variables only work in the back-end.

I tried changing the post requset to:

```
  axios.post( "http://localhost:5000/sendEmail" || "/sendEmail"   , data)
```

In hopes that this would work when I use my local host on port 5000 and also on my website when the relative path would work. Instead it just tries to send the first post request even thought that server isn't running. Is something wrong with how I've used || here? Would trying to send a post request to both be a bad fix??

Answer (score 0):

For heroku I think you have to take the port from the environment variable `PORT`. Change a like in your program which looks for port as,

```js
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

This will take the currect port for heroku and run in 8080 locally and change you url to just `/sendEmail`. `||` statements don't work like that it is logical OR. Just say the url in a relative way

```js
axios.post( "/sendEmail", data)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data))
        .then((response) => {
            if(response.statusText === "OK" && response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                return response.json()
            } else {
                throw new Error("Server can't be reached!")
            }
        })
        .then((json) => {
            console.log("It is JSON")
         })
        .catch(err => console.log('Could not send email: ' + err));
      }
```

Comment: I have this line in my code, but I never bothered to set the environment variable PORT to anything since I figured it would just default to the 8080. Are you saying I need to set this variable? Or is it simply the presence of this line that should make it work?

Comment: If you don't want to start on another port no need to add this, but when running on heroky you should add this line because heroku might run your app on a different port. If it is not a port problem I suggest you look at your logs. How is your setup firstly, front-end and back-end in same server? Can you show more of the code.

Comment: Ah I think I might see an issue. When I send the post request from the front end I use the URL: localhost:PORT/sendEmail or the URL of the actual website (websiteURL/sendEmail). What would be the correct URL to send the post request to given that the port can vary?

Comment: Also I checked the logs just to be safe and it does indeed start the server, so that's all fine and like you suggest it was on a completely random port like 40000 something.

Comment: Yes.change the URL in the webpage request. That is the problem. If both front-end and back-end is running on the same server just set a relative URL and all should work fine, hopefully.

Comment: On my localhost if I try a relative URL since the post request is being sent from the front end it will be relative to that URL and not the port used by the backend. On the real website this would work fine I'm guessing? So I'll try ./sendEamil || https://localhost:5000/sendEmail and let ya know how it goes.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please accept if it works

Comment: This breaks. The relative path becomes relative to the front end URL which is hosted on PORT 3000 when the back end is port = 5000 or 8080 or whatever. So this breaks when I try to run it on my local machine. Do I have some structure wrong? I think that they should be separate entities?? Thanks

Comment: So, you have a seperate backend and front end. Ok
Then first host both of them. Then put the URL as a full url of the hosted backend.(sorry for replying so late)

Comment: No worries. Thanks I'll try that. Pretty sure it'll work!